# Script to create same Google Classroom assignment for each day of the school year

Tags: google-classroom

Does anyone know of a script that I could adapt to create the same assignment for each school day of a given school year?  For example, I would like to create the assignment "Practice your Anki deck.  Submit screenshot of your stats" every school day in our class BasicSkills.  Ideally, the assignment would be scheduled the week before it was due.  This would be a great time saver for those of us elementary school teachers using Google Classroom who have lots of daily and weekly repeating tasks.

I was a programmer many years ago and could adapt an existing script but would struggle to get this working just based on the API description.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can, it just depends on how you'll approach it. I'll give you a skeletal structure of the code:

```
function myFunction() {


  Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
  return dat;
}


  var i;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      var dat = new Date();
      Logger.log(dat.addDays(i))

      var ClassSource =  {
    title: "Test File" + dat.addDays(i),
    state: "DRAFT",
    workType: "ASSIGNMENT"
  };

  Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create(ClassSource, 4965804775)
}
  //Logger.log(exec);
}
```

How to approach your goal:

Ideally you want to create the assignment in one go but I don't recommend since there are [limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) that you'll encounter (e.g. timeout).

Next, if ever you'll decide to do it in one go, I recommend you to use `Utilities.sleep(1000)` between calls.

You can also create a list of dates that don't have a class like saturday, sunday, holiday.

Sample result:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  Will give it a try this weekend!